# Java - All characters have a numerical value?

Tags: java, numerical

I am doing some homework for my first programming class, yay! :)

However, one of the programs I need to do, sorts any set of characters that a user inputs. It can be any character (& or $ or 5 or F).

So far I have done this with only letters:

```
if (a.compareTo(b)<=0 && a.compareTo(c)<=0)
```

or for numbers:

```
if (a<=b && a<=c)
```

But does java apply a numerical value to all the characters, or how does java sort characters like $ and @?

(I have found similar questions, but they were all in C++, I'm too much of a newbie to understand the similarities, I tried though)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah. Java uses ASCII values of characters to compare them. Did you try it?

Comment: @RohitJain yeah, my first line of code there, works already! Thanks for kindly pointing out that I had already done it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All characters do have numeric values assigned according to their corresponding codepoints in UNICODE (the initial 127 UNICODE code points match [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) codes).

Specifically, the numeric code of the "at" sign `@` is 64, and the code of the dollar sign '$' is 36.

Also note that digits are characters as well, so they too have numeric values (48 through 57).